# According to pdf_reference_1-7, ToUnicode CMap have a greater priority than encoding, but here I have a contrary file, what should I do

Tags: pdf, pdfminer

origin code: (\037)Tj

CID 31 should be mapped into '✓' according to encoding Differences [which is right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg9ZN.png)

BaseEncoding: WinAnsiEncoding

Differences: [31, uni2713]

CID 31 is mapped into '3' according to ToUnicode CMap which is wrong

CMap:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
2 beginbfchar
<1F> <0033>
<0020> <0020>
endbfchar
endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end
```

Comment: *"what should I do"* - what's the context? Are you responsible for the program that generated that pdf and gave to fix that program? That being said, **uni2713** is not a standard glyph name as described in the pdf specification.

Comment: I'm writing a program extracting text from pdf, Mac's Preview renders the pdf content to  '✓',  but my program renders it to '3', I think I write a bug or I miss something about encoding, but I don't know how to fix it. It's right that uni2713 is not a standard glyph name, but U+2713 do be  '✓' and Preview renders it.

Comment: *"I'm writing a program extracting text from pdf"* - in that case this is just a start. You'll find out soon that there are many pdf files which have incorrect information for text extraction, some by error, some by negligence, some by intention.

Comment: Well, this is why I am writing myself a pdf text extraction program, I find that there is no program good enough to extract text and tables from pdf. Anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PDF format the rendering, and text extraction, are two separate paths. Unlike say HTML, in PDF, these are two separate actions.

According to what you provided, the page content stream has character code \037 (octal). For rendering, the encoding is used, of which Differences is part of, so the glyph index at font encoding uni2713 is used.

However, for text extraction the ToUnicode CMap is used. You can verify this by opening the PDF in various PDF readers, and copy+paste the text into a text editor.

The reason for this is that while character codes can only map to one glyph in a particular font, that same character code can map to multiple unicode values. Say U+FB01 (ligature).

> find that there is no program good enough to extract text and tables from pdf.

You may not have seen the text and table extraction tool the company I work for has developed.
https://www.pdftron.com/document-understanding

https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-tools/pdf-table-extraction

Comment: By the way, I think your Demo product(https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-tools/pdf-table-extraction/) is not good enough in table extract. This one(https://pdflux.com) is the best one I have already found(but still has a little problem), what I am doing is to do better than this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We are just about to release a major update. Beta is starting, and online demo will be available in the coming weeks/months.

Comment: I'm very interested in table extraction, I will try your new release then.